# custom module css not add

Tags: theming, javascript

```
function doLookup($baseRootDir) {
  if (variable_get('xmldata')) {
    $xmldata = variable_get('xmldata');
  } else {
    $xmldata = '';
  }
  $rootDir = realpath($baseRootDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $xmldata);
  $di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootDir);

  foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di) as $filename => $file) {
    $fileInfo = new SplFileInfo($filename);
    if (strtolower($fileInfo->getExtension()) == "css") {
      // Include this CSS file in drupal
      $cssFileName =  preg_replace("@[\\\]+@", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, str_replace($baseRootDir, "", $filename));
      drupal_add_css($cssFileName, array('type' => 'external', 'group' => CSS_SYSTEM, 'every_page' => TRUE,));
    } elseif (strtolower($fileInfo->getExtension()) == "js") {
        // Include this JS file in drupal
        $js = str_replace($baseRootDir, "", $filename);
        drupal_add_js($js, array('group' => CSS_SYSTEM, 'every_page' => TRUE));
    }
  }
}
```

Function is running properly.

Here `$cssFileName= "/bijli/model/model.css"` which is correct, here `bijli` is general directory not root directory.

I am not able to see any error. What can be the reason?

Comment: Try to check after removing `'type' => 'external'`.

Comment: Which version of Drupal? And where is this code placed? If it's executed too late, CSS might be not added.

Comment: Also try to use the name like "bijli/model/model.css". Here I assume `bijli` directory is placed in root directory of drupal.

Comment: 1). 'type'=>'external' is complete remove or 'type'=> 'other option' is used

Comment: 2). Drupal 7.33 i used

Comment: 3). I am trying to use "bijli/model/model.css" but result is same